# Encrypt a file appending wrapped key in unique file

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rsa

I'm trying to encrypt a file using AES key Wrapped in a RSA key pair..

I'm trying to put the wrapped key at beginning of the file, and then for decrypting I take the first 256 bytes of the wrapped key for taking it.

The problem is I'm encrypting the file in blocks of 1024 bytes. So, for decrypting, I need to take the last bytes of the file (not the first 256 because they are the key)

So in [this image](http://s1.postimg.org/o7bhp6127/Blank_Flowchart_New_Page.jpg) you can see the proces

```html
<a href='http://postimg.org/image/htmelww63/' target='_blank'><img src='http://s1.postimg.org/htmelww63/Blank_Flowchart_New_Page.jpg' border='0' alt="Blank Flowchart New Page" /></a>
```

So the problem is when I need to decrypt the file except the first 256 bytes. I can't find a working algorithm...

Here the code for encrypting:

```
public static void fileEncripWrapped(File in, File out, PublicKey pub, byte [] key) {  

    try {
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

        //Encrypting wrapped key      
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, pub);
        byte[] encKey = cipher.wrap(keySpec);

        FileOutputStream osAppend  = new FileOutputStream(out);

        osAppend.write(encKey);
        osAppend.close();


        // Crypting the file 
         cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);

        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(in);
        CipherOutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(out, true), cipher);

        copy(is, os);

        is.close();
        os.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Ha succeït un error xifrant: " + ex);
    }
}
```

This is the code I use for copy the inputStream to the outputStream in blocks of 1024 Bytes.

```
private static void copy(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    int i;
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    while((i=is.read(b))!=-1) {
       os.write(b, 0, i);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is for uncrypting:

```
public static void fileUncryptWrapped(File in, File out, PrivateKey priv) { 

   try {

       Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
       cipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, priv);

       //First we must to take the wrapped key in the first 256 bytes of the file: 
       byte[] bufferKey = new byte[256];
       InputStream is = new FileInputStream(in);
       if (is.read(bufferKey) != bufferKey.length) { 

       }
       is.close();

       Key ky = cipher.unwrap(bufferKey, "AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);¡

       // Now we must to uncrypt the rest of the file
       cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
       cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, ky);

       CipherInputStream ix = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(in), cipher);
       FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(out);

       copy(ix, os);

       ix.close();
       os.close();

   } catch (Exception ex) {
       System.err.println("Ha succeït un error xifrant: " + ex);
   }
}
```

What modifications do I need to do in the copy function for taking the bytes after the first 256? I tried something like that but it doesn't work...

```
// Get the size of the file
long streamLength = inputStream.available();

if (streamLength > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    // File is too large
}

// Create the byte array to hold the data
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

// Read in the bytes
int block_size = 1024;
int offset = 256;
int numRead = 0;
while (offset < (int) streamLength && (numRead = inputStream.read(bytes, offset,  block_size)) >= 0) {
    offset += numRead;
    outputStream.write(bytes, 0 , block_size );
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You decryption code should look something like this:

```
public static void fileDecryptWrapped(File in, File out, PrivateKey priv)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WITHRSA");
    signature.initSign(priv);
    signature.update("test".getBytes());
    byte[] bufferKey = signature.sign();

    // First we must to take the wrapped key in the first bufferKey.length bytes of the file
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(in);
    if (is.read(bufferKey) != bufferKey.length) { 
        is.close();
        throw new IllegalStateException("Too short file");
    }

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, priv);
    Key aesKey = cipher.unwrap(bufferKey, "AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);

    // Now we must to decrypt the rest of the file
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);

    CipherInputStream ix = new CipherInputStream(is, cipher);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(out);

    copy(ix, os);

    ix.close();
    os.close();
}
```

Note that the same `FileInputStream` after reading the key is being passed to `CipherInputStream` without modifications.

The problem I see with your approach, there is no structure in encrypted file. For example, using non 2K RSA key will badly fail as decryption algorithm always expects 256 bytes of wrapped key.

Comment: Ok but i can get back my wrapped key. So the problem basically is how to read the rest of the file in blocks of 1024. How do you think i must to do the approach?

Comment: `CipherInputStream` does that for you.

Comment: Ok it works! Using the same  FileInputStream  of the first 256... A newbie error! thx! Maybe there are a better thing for do that?

Comment: See updated response. Since you know the RSA key and wrapped key length is equal to the length of the RSA key, you can do proper initialization. Unfortunately PrivateKey doesn't have any API to get a modulus, so I had to do signing to get the length.